# REST Framework authentication tokens changed / deleted after Django 1.9 -> 2.1 and rest framework 3.6.3 -> 3.8.2 update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.7

We have noticed, that at least some of our authentication tokens have changed (or been invalidated) since we updated to Django 2.1

Does anyone have any Ideas what could have caused this? While using a refresh token etc. would be good, I thought these tokens to be permanent.